# Readability trade-off with fwarn-name-shadowing

Tags: haskell, ghc

I recently turned on GHC's `-Wall` option, which includes [`-fwarn-name-shadowing`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.0-latest/docs/html/users_guide/options-sanity.html). The rationale offered is:

> This option causes a warning to be emitted whenever an inner-scope value has the same name as an outer-scope value, i.e. the inner value shadows the outer one. This can catch typographical errors that turn into hard-to-find bugs.

But in practice I haven't caught any bugs with it yet, but I *have* made the variable naming in my functions a lot more awkward to work around it. Abbreviated example:

```
-- General method for parsing a paragraph.
paragraph :: Parser Node
paragraph = undefined -- omitted for brevity

blockquote :: Parser Node
blockquote =   lookAhead (char '>')
           >>  Blockquote
           <$> paragraph' `sepBy1` blankLine
  where
    -- Avoid shadowing a `paragraph` method defined above.
    -- This one is more specialized and relevant only in
    -- this context.
    paragraph' = Paragraph <$> body
```

This seems a bit smelly to me, but I have other cases that are much worse — for example I have one function where I end up avoiding shadowing `remainder` and `sections` by using `remainder'` and `sections'`, and then in a nested `where` clause I go straight to `r` and `s` to avoid further shadowing — and I'm wondering whether `-fwarn-name-shadowing` is on the balance net positive. I think there is some refactoring I can do to avoid some shadowing without incurring the indirection of these awkward names, but it's not always possible.

Am I better off allowing some shadowing, or should I instead be looking to refactor examples like this to make the smell go away? I suspect the latter, but I am not sure.

Comment: This irks me too sometimes. What I really want is some way to have the compiler magically warn me about *accidentally* shadowed names, but not when I was deliberately reusing a name. The only way that could work without magic is if I'm marking deliberate cases of shadowing; I should probably mark the *uses* of the shadowed name too, to make sure I'm not being brain-dead and trying to refer to two different things with the same name from the same scope. But it's hard to think of a way of marking allowed shadowing with less syntactic overhead than just sticking ' on things!

Comment: I always stick to silence the warning by renaming bindings, but I think it's a matter of personal preference. I like to see an identifier in the middle of the code and know that if it has a top-level binding then it's really that. Further, in defining auxiliary functions it's easy to reuse some argument name like `xs` and then confuse the two bindings. Sometimes, one can also write an accidentally recursive binding. Still, I can see that sometimes the warning is a bit annoying.

Comment: @ben, I think anything you prefix with `_` won't warn, so that might be an option too. That way if you wanted to re-use and nest `foo` twice you could do `_foo`, `_foo`, `_foo` instead of `foo`, `foo'`, `foo''`.

Comment: Stupid question but how is paragraph different from paragraph' ? I mean if they are different, you should be able to find two different names and if not maybe you only need one.

Comment: The type of bug it found is when you for example uses paragraph but make a typo  in it's definition (paragraph for example) if both have the same type it is really to find the bug.

Comment: They are indeed different @mb14, but to give the different names could be cumbersome: in this case they are really `paragraph` and `paragraphInTheContextOfABlockquote`. I guess I could call the latter `blockquoteParagraph`, but it does seem to be a bit lengthy compared to most names I see in Haskell.

Answer (score 1):

Fair enough , I just add a similar problem where finding two different name is difficult. I still think name shadowing us a code smell and trying to find different meaningful names must be considered first.